# How do I get the all time data from Google Fit API?

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I need to get the number of steps the user walked since he started using the app till today. How do I do this using the Google FIT api?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Fitness History API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history) that enables your app to perform bulk operations on the fitness store such as reading, inserting, updating, and deleting fitness data.

You need to create a `DataReadRequest` instance to read data from the fitness history.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = new Date();
cal.setTime(now);
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
Log.e("History", "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
Log.e("History", "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

//Check how many steps were walked and recorded in the last 7 days
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();
```

You can also group this data together in `Bucket` objects by time or sessions. For this example, you request aggregated step data for the last week and bucket that data by day.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = new Date();
cal.setTime(now);
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
    .setAppPackageName(this)
    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
    .setName("Step Count")
    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
    .build();

int stepCountDelta = 1000000;
DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);

DataPoint point = dataSet.createDataPoint()
        .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
point.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).setInt(stepCountDelta);
dataSet.add(point);
```

This example from this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-fit-for-android-history-api--cms-25856) uses aggregated data points where each `DataPoint` represents the number of steps walked in a day.

Check this related So questions:

- [How to get step count from Google Fit REST API like Google Fit app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998823/how-to-get-step-count-from-google-fit-rest-api-like-google-fit-app)
- [How do I retrieve step count data from Google Fitness REST api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158645/how-do-i-retrieve-step-count-data-from-google-fitness-rest-api)

Comment: now if want to get the data ever since the user started using the app, till today, what will be the startTime and endTime? And what bucketing strategy should i use?

Comment: My question was how to find out the number of steps walked ever since the time user installed the app, till now. Your answer is totally irrelavant.

Comment: Based from my example, you can use `DataReadRequest` to check how many steps were walked and recorded. Once you have your `DataReadRequest` created, you can request data from the `GoogleApiClient` using the `Fitness.HistoryApi.readData` command as stated [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-fit-for-android-history-api--cms-25856). If the call returns successfully, you are able to access the user's fitness data from the `DataReadResult` object.

Comment: @abielita Can you please help me with sleep data in Google Fit? Here is my question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/43780050/7382665

Answer (score 1):

I've had that question myself. What i did was build a DataRequest with:

**endTime now (today):**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = new Date();
cal.setTime(now);
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

**and start time when the first version of Google fit app was released:**

```
cal.set(2014, 9, 28);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); //so it get all day and not the current hour
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); //so it get all day and not the current minute
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

**DataReadRequest build:** (you can bucket if you want)

```
        DataReadRequest readRequest =  new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .read(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .enableServerQueries()
                .build();
```

This way you get all the data starting from 28 October 2014

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution given by JPL and it worked for me, don't use .bucketByTime() attribute, in the response you will get List of DataSet

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.set(2014, 9, 28);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); 
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
   DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .build();
```

In response use:

```
                 if (response.getDataSets().size()>0){
                    for (DataSet dataSet :response.getDataSets())
                    dumpDataSet(dataSet);
                }
```